# Trying to create user from text file but keep getting invalid user name error in Ubuntu

Tags: linux, user-management

I am now trying to create users in Ubuntu from a text file and it looks like this:

```
student1
student2
student3
student4
student5
```

However, I keep getting invalid user name error. For instance
'seradd: invalid user name 'student5

Here is my code. The first argument is input file and the second input is output file. Can anyone help?

```
#!/bin/bash
if test ${#} -lt 1 
then
    echo "Please provide the input file"
    exit 1
else
    cat ${1} | while read user
    do
        randompw=$(cat /dev/urandom | tr -dc 'a-zA-Z0-9' | fold -w 8 | head -n 1)
        useradd -m -s /bin/bash ${user}
        echo ${newuser}:${randompw} | chpasswd
        if test $# -lt 2
            then
                echo ${newuser}:${randompw} >> pwlist.txt
            else
                echo ${newuser}:${randompw} >> ${2}
            fi
        if id -u ${user}
            then
                echo "User account ${user} created successfully"
            else
                echo "User account ${user} created unsuccessfully"
            fi
    done
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

The variable `newuser` is not defined. I think you meant `$user` instead.

Suggestion:

- Enclose variable references and computations within double quotes. I fixed that.

```sh
#!/bin/bash
if test ${#} -lt 1
then
    echo "Please provide the input file"
    exit 1
else
    cat "${1}" | while read user
    do
        randompw="$(cat /dev/urandom | tr -dc 'a-zA-Z0-9' | fold -w 8 | head -n 1)"
        useradd -m -s /bin/bash "${user}"
        echo "${user}:${randompw}" | chpasswd
        if test $# -lt 2
            then
                echo "${user}:${randompw}" >> pwlist.txt
            else
                echo "${user}:${randompw}" >> ${2}
            fi
        if id -u "${user}"
            then
                echo "User account ${user} created successfully"
            else
                echo "User account ${user} created unsuccessfully"
            fi
    done
fi
```

Comment: Thanks. However, I have edited the code according to your fixed one and it's still giving the same error

Comment: `'seradd: invalid user name 'student1                                                                                    ) pam_chauthtok() failed, error:                                                                                        Authentication token manipulation error                                                                                 ) password not changedr student1                                                                                        id: 'student1\r': no such user